# Sequence reconstruction from ordered subsamples

Tags: combinatorics, sequence

Given a sequence (we'll assume of integers) like

```mathematica
seq = {1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1}
```

I can take a random permutation

```mathematica
perm = BlockRandom[
 RandomChoice@Permutations[{1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1}]
 ]

{1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1}
```

and given some set of splits (say `{3, 1, 3}`) from this permutation I get the subsequences

```mathematica
subseqs = TakeList[perm, {3, 1, 3}]

{{1, 0, 1}, {2}, {0, 0, 1}}
```

Is there a convenient way to show that this split permutation can *also* be obtained by taking three *ordered* subsets of the original sequence for example as

```
subseqs == { seq[[{1, 2, 4}]], seq[[{5}]], seq[[{3, 6, 7}]] }
```

where each set of subsample indices is strictly increasing?

More importantly, in cases where this *doesn't* work, e.g. `{{2, 1, 1}, {0}, {0, 1, 0}}` or more subtly `{{1, 1, 0}, {0}, {1, 2, 0}}` is there an easy way to check that?

The obvious solution of doing a single pass through and just trying to build the given subset (i.e. for `{1, 0, 1}` just taking elements `{1, 2, 4}`) is promising, but will break for something like `{{1, 2, 1}, {0}, {1, 0, 0}}`, which corresponds to (among others) the subsamples `{{4, 5, 7}, {2}, {1, 3, 6}}`

I know that this problem is basically equivalent to finding the unique ordered subsets of the original sequence, and of course I could just check against all ordered subsets of `Range[7]`, but that kind of solution will quickly get unwieldy